# Interesting construct, grammatically unclear

Tags: grammar, archaicisms

A *Financial Times* article has the following sentence:

> There isn’t a Classics or History of Art equivalent of a Cambridge don inviting a Madras clerk over on the strength of his papers, **as GH Hardy did Ramanujan.**

I fully understand its meaning, but I'm fascinated from a grammar point of view by the "as GH Hardy did Ramanujan" part. Is it an archaic construct?

I understand the verb *to invite* is transitive, which presumably explains the usage of *do* in the clause. Still, to a non-native ear, the lingering feeling is that a preposition could fit between "did" and "Ramanujan", had everyday language been employed.

Comment: By the way, always trust the grammar of the Financial Times. There is simply no other publication like it in the English language.

Comment: "Did" is a pro-VP used for VP reduction. It's understood anaphorically as "GH Hardy invited Ramanuham over on the strength of his papers".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Did* refers to the action previously mentioned - "as G.H. Hardy [invited] [Ramanujan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srinivasa_Ramanujan) over [on the strength of his papers]."

No, it isn't an archaic construct.

> I'm bringing up my children to enjoy being outdoors, as my parents did me. (in the same way that my parents brought me up.)

Comment: Not so sure why the "I fully understand its meaning" was edited to "vaguely" though, I am not stupid enough not to understand such a simple sentence.

Comment: I'd say it's somewhere along an old-fashioned ... rarefied continuum.

Comment: This is called do-support. You avoid repeating the main verb and use did instead. It is just quite formal here as it replaces a gerund noun/verb phrase.